# Printing Scrollable Bootstrap Modal adds extra pages at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a scrollable bootstrap modal with a print button on top of it. When user clicks it, i'm printing the modal. Below is the code,
HTML :

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="body-noPrint">
    /* HTML BODY CONTENT */
</div>

<div id="print-content">
     <!--PRINT PREVIEW MODAL MARKUP-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="printViewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">                                
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="modal-Printbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span> Print</button>
                          </div><!--MODAL HEADER CLOSE-->
                          <div class="modal-body">
                              <!--DISPLAY THIS ROW AT MODAL VIEW-->
                                <div class="row">
                                        /* HEADER UI */                     
                                </div><!--MODAL VIEW HEADER CONTENT CLOSE-->

                              <!--DISPLAY THIS ROW AT PRINT-->
                                <div class="row" style="display:none;"> 
                                        /* HEADER PRINT */
                                </div><!--PRINT VIEW HEADER CONTENT CLOSE-->

                              <!--PRINT VIEW DYNAMIC TABLE-->
                                <div class="table-responsive" id="modalTable">
                                    <table id="modalTbl" class="table table-bordered">
                                      <thead>
                                        <tr class="active">
                                            <th class='col-xs-6'></th>
                                            <th class='col-xs-1'></th>
                                            <th class='col-xs-5'></th>
                                        </tr>
                                      </thead> 
                                      <tbody>               
                                      </tbody>           
                                    </table>                            
                                </div>                                                                                        
                        </div>                
                    </div>
              </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$('#prntBtn').click(function(){
    window.print();
});
```

CSS :

```
@media print{
  /* Below CSS Makes Modal Content Visible At Print */
    body.modal-open {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    body.modal-open .modal .modal-header,
    body.modal-open .modal .modal-body {
        visibility: visible;  /* make visible modal body and header */
    }

    body.modal-open .modal {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: visible!important;
    }

/*Print Preview Modal Styling CSS*/    
    #printViewModal .modal-dialog {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #printViewModal .modal-content {      
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 0;
      overflow:auto;
    }

    #printViewModal *{
        font-size:x-small !important;
    }

    #modalTbl thead tr > th{
        text-align:center;
    }

    #modalTbl tbody tr > td{
        text-align:left;
    }

    #modalTable{
        margin-top:10px;
    } 
}
```

I got a suggestion from stack overflow to replace 'visibility : hidden', for that i tried 'display : none', but this displays blank page at print.

Can someone please help me, in getting rid of these extra pages when printing.

Comment: What HTML is inside your modal? That seems like it might be the most important part here. Try to provide enough information so that someone can easily reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Zack, Updated my question with HTML code, please suggest.

Comment: Your `window.print()` call will print *everything* on the page, so you aren't just printing your modal, you are printing the entire page, so that may be why you get multiple pages. It might be worth it to try using a pop up window instead of a modal to display your printable content, so that way you can control exactly what content you want to print when they click the print button. FWIW, I only got one page with your HTML example.

Comment: @Zack, How can i print only modal content, ignoring page content. I have a dynamically generated table which pulls the data from Sharepoint List and appends to the table. That's the reason, you got one page with my example. Sorry about that, can you suggest me better way to print only modal ignoring page content? As suggested, i have tried 'popup window', whereas it is messing all the CSS.

Comment: @Zack, this is what i tried, var html = $('#printViewModal').html();   
   var win = window.open('','printwindow');
   win.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../CSS/bootstrap.min.css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="../../CSS/newVst.css"/>');
  $(win.document.body).html(html);  I'm doing this on print button click.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable this option [Background graphics] to see what is extra printed on your page.
Hope this helps to find out the root cause.

[image]